# join as an alternative to multiple OR's

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have two tables with the following structure:

```
table name: friends
uid (PK)(FK)
friend_id (PK)(FK)

table name: posts
post_id (AI)(PK)
post_text
uid (FK) //poster id
```

I'd like to select posts that were only made from friends of user `x`.
My inital plan was to use the following code:

```
SELECT posts.post_text INNER JOIN friends ON posts.uid = friends.friend_id 
WHERE friends.uid = x
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. (I get all posts done by x, done all posts done by X's **friends**. The only alternative I can think of is to use a (possibly very long) string of OR's - as in

```
WHERE posts.uid = 'friend_id_1' OR posts.uid = 'friend_id_2' ect..
```

Any alternative solutions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  posts.*
FROM    friends
JOIN    posts
ON      posts.uid = friends.friend_id
WHERE   friends.uid = 'x'
```

This query should work, so you better check your data.

Didn't you occasionally make `X` his own friend?

If you friendship relation is *symmetrical*, i. e. if `X` is a friend to `Y`, then `Y` is a friend to `X`, then you should make the table as this:

```
friends (a, b, PRIMARY KEY (a, b), KEY (b))

SELECT  posts.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  b AS friend_id
        FROM    friends
        WHERE   a = 'X'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  a AS friend_id
        FROM    friends
        WHERE   b = 'X'
        ) friends
JOIN    posts
ON      posts.uid = friends.friend_id
```

Before inserting a pair of friends, always arrange it so that `A < B`, i. e. the user with the least `user_id` goes into `A`.

Comment: If your data does indeed have x as a friend of themselves, you can exclude that case by adding: "AND friends.friend_id != x" to this query.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT posts.post_text INNER JOIN friends ON posts.uid = friends.friend_id 
Inner join friends fr on friends.friend_id = fr.uid
WHERE friends.uid = x
```